# JavaScript: Setting variable to new function on created object, it still calls old function

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, callback

I've got a "class" that looks like this:

```
export function IBXMReplay() {
    var onRow = function(){console.log("not right")};
    ....
}
```

Later on, it's called in a function like this:

```
var seqRow = function() {
    onRow();
    ....
}
```

This function is essentially called by callbacks for web audio getAudio. I construct the object like this:

```
var replay = new IBXMReplay();
replay.onRow = function(){console.log("Right")};
```

However, when onRow() is called, it always prints `"not right."`

What am I doing wrong??? I tried creating a setter function but that didn't work either.

Comment: well, you assigned the onRow to a new function on the object replay. So, ify you want it to do what you want in "seqRow" you'd have to do replay.onRow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `onRow` function is being defined as a variable in the `IBXMReplay` local scope, and i'm assuming that the `seqRow` function is also inside `IBXMReplay`.  Local-scope variables cannot be directly accessed nor modified from the outside.

For this to work, you'd need to make the `onRow` function a *property* of the `IBXMReplay` object (in JS functions are objects too):

```
export function IBXMReplay() {
    this.onRow = function(){console.log("not right")};
    ....
}
```

Or better yet, store it in the *prototype*:

```
var IBXMReplay = function IBXMReplay() {
    ....
}
IBXMReplay.prototype.onRow = function(){console.log("not right")};
export IBXMReplay
```

Either way, you can later do:

```
var replay = new IBXMReplay();
replay.onRow = function(){console.log("Right")};
```

It should work as you expected.

---

Now, some explanation about that.  Let's say you have 100 instances of the `IBXMReplay` 'class'.  The differences between storing it as an object property vs. a prototype property are subtle but important:

#### Object property

Storing the method like `this.onRow` will mean there'll be 100 copies of it in memory.  If you later edit it with `replay.onRow = something`, it'll be completely replaced for that particular instance.

Doing something like `delete replay.onRow` would not bring the original function back and will instead throw an 'undefined is not a function' error when executing that instance..

#### Prototype property

Storing the function in the object's prototype instead will mean there'll only be a single copy of `onRow` being referenced by all instances.  When editing the instance with `replay.onRow = something`, the underlying prototype `onRow` is merely being *shadowed* by an object property with the same name, so any calls inside the `IBXMReplay` class will reference the overriding function instead.

Deleting the instance property `delete replay.onRow` will 'uncover' the original function.

This is how JavaScript works, and is called the *prototype chain*.  Whenever you do `foo.bar`, a `bar` property is searched directly in the `foo` object, but if not found then it's searched in `foo`'s prototype, and then the prototype's prototype, and so on, until reaching `null`, which has no prototype.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed write up.